# Error using Kundan Augmented SDK

Tags: c#, unity-container, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Hi I am trying to use Kundan SDK by following the tutorial given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-SiR_qJwaU). However when I download and open Kundan SDK, I am seeing the following error below:

The type or namespace name `Editor' does not exist in the namespace`Unity'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

The Kundan Tracker.cs can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3wtLErKuTFJYmVnc2trZWRRTjQ).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which line of code are you getting that error on?

Comment: Assets/KudanAR/Scripts/Components/KudanTracker.cs(4,13): error CS0234:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 4, it has `using Unity.Editor;`. There is no nested namespace called `Editor` or `Unity.Editor;`.

There is one called `UnityEditor` and I believe that's what the author of that script wanted to write and that was a typo or mistake to add "." between `Unity` and `Editor`.

I would have said you should simply replace `using Unity.Editor;` line of code with `using UnityEditor;` but on the sixth line of the script, you already have `using UnityEditor;` wrapped around `UNITY_EDITOR` to make sure that the script successfully builds for standalone devices.

Remove the `using Unity.Editor` from line 4 and this problem should go away.